# Getting data for yesterday is not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying something really simple: get all records that have yesterday's date in the `SomeDATE` column.

First, I tried this:

```
Declare @StartDate  Date = DateAdd(dd, -1, GetDate())
```

... and then put this in the `WHERE` clause:

```
Where SomeDATE = @StartDate
```

I got no records returned.

[*Today being 2018-02-22*]:

If I use

```
Where SomeDATE = '2018-02-21'
```

I get the records that I need for yesterday.

I have also tried this:

```
Declare @StartDate  Date = DateAdd(dd, -2, GetDate())
Declare @EndDate    Date = GetDate()
```

and this in the where clause:

```
Where (SomeDATE > @StartDate And SomeDATE < @EndDate)
```

again - no results.

Am I missing something really basic?

I mean I *should* be able to just do this:

```
Where SomeDATE = DateAdd(dd, -1, GetDate())
```

and that should be the same as hard-coding yesterday's date in. Right?

Comment: Check your column `someDate`, is it a `(var)char(10)`+ or is it a `date/datetime`. If it is a char, it would explain it.

Answer (score 0):

Right after I posted my question, I tried this in my where clause:

```
Where SomeDATE = Cast(DATEADD(dd, -1, GetDate()) As Date)
```

and that works. I don't understand why it works with the Cast().

@Patrick: the SomeDATE col is in a Table Variable in the Query and is defined [by me] as 'Date'. I have a feeling that it has something to do with your suggestion about the Data Types not being an exact match. I appreciate  your help!

Comment: if compare a date to column to a explicit variable then you have to cast... otherwise the implicit variable should just work fine.. normally i use day

Comment: @talay can you post a complete script that reproduces the problem?   I'm with Zohar here.

Comment: Getdate() returns date along with time.  Using CAST function, you're removing time and only focusing on date comparison.

Answer (score 0):

GetDate() return a value of type DATETIME, @StartDate is for type Date, so you must cast the return value to date:

```
Declare @StartDate  Date = cast(DateAdd(dd, -2, GetDate()), as date)
Declare @EndDate    Date = cast(GetDate() as date)

Where SomeDATE = @StartDate
```